# Question about Automate the Boring Stuff: Chapter 5

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to programming, and am currently working through Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, 2nd edition. In Chapter 5, there's a practice question that involves creating a Fantasy Game Inventory using dictionaries. I had completed the problem using others' answers, however, I do not understand a specific portion of the code.

This code means to add the new "dragonLoot" list to a current inventory, which is the dictionary "inv". Here is my code:

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
         item_total = item_total + v
         print(str(v) + " " + k)
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
        inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
    return inventory



inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)

displayInventory(inv)
```

My question relates to this specific section:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
for i in addedItems:
    inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
    inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
return inventory
```

When entering "inventory.setdefault(i ,0)", and then "inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1", how does this code allow the list to be added to the dictionary?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break the loop in `addToInventory` function down. First we have

```python
inventory.setdefault(i ,0)
```

This instruction means “if key `i` is not already in the `inventory` dictionary, set it to `0`. It is - in this case (because we do not use the return value of [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)) - equivalent to

```python
if i not in inventory.keys():
    inventory[i] = 0
```

Next comes this instruction

```python
inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
```

Which is basically an [incrementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators), *i.e.* add 1 to `inventory` value for key `i`.

Explained otherwise, that `for` loop is “for every item in `addedItems`, set the corresponding value in `inventory` dictionary to zero if not already present, then increment it”.

---

After you are done with this book, you may benefit from taking some time checking out Python standard library's [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html) module, especially [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that would much better suit that logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Okay, so because the inventory is being incremented + 1, I understand that it may cause a value like "dagger" to be 1, because its current value is 0. However, how do the "gold coins" become 45 from the original 42? If everything in the dictionary is to be incremented by +1, wouldn't "gold coins" value be 43? As this should also be incremented by 1.

Comment: Because look in the `addedItems` list, there are three occurrences of `"gold coin"`. Incrementation will hence occur three times: `42 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 45`.

Comment: Hm okay. However, there is also a "gold coin" value of 42. Would that also not be added by 1? Making the total 43 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 46?

Comment: No because that precisely the dictionary value we are adding _to_.

Comment: Okay I understand, because "i" values are resulting from addedItems only. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is protecting against a `KeyError` if the dictionary key has not already been set. You can also use a defaultdict from the collections module in the standard library.

Consider the following

```
inventory = {}
addedItems = ['1', '2', '3']
addToInventory(inventory, addedItems)
```

You get the correct output even though inventory was empty. This is because `setdefault` ensures that the key will be created with the default value if it doesn't already exist. It saves you from having to use an `if/then` statement about whether the key is already in the dict.

```
{'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1}
```

Now try the same function without the `setdefault` line

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
    return inventory

inventory = {}
addedItems = ['1', '2', '3']
addToInventory(inventory, addedItems)

=== Output: ===
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-8302116925c5> in <module>
      6 inventory = {}
      7 addedItems = ['1', '2', '3']
----> 8 addToInventory(inventory, addedItems)

<ipython-input-137-8302116925c5> in addToInventory(inventory, addedItems)
      1 def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
      2     for i in addedItems:
----> 3         inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
      4     return inventory
      5 

KeyError: '1'
```

Now look at what happens if you use `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
    return inventory

inventory = defaultdict(int)
addedItems = ['1', '2', '3']
addToInventory(inventory, addedItems)

=== Output: ===
Out[143]: defaultdict(int, {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1})
```